# Menu item is not shown (width of variable is miscalculated)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is about the following code (not written by me):

http://codepen.io/lukejacksonn/pen/PwmwWV

## Problem

Somehow the `var availableSpace` is being miscalculated when the page is loaded originally at ~1125px*, hiding the last menu item and showing the hamburger button in stead:

[image: Original view when you load the page]

When you make the browser window wider until the hamburger button disappears and then more narrow again to ~1125px, `var availableSpace` is calculated correctly and shows the last menu item:

[image: Image after the browser window was resized]

## Question

How do I calculate `var availableSpace` so that (when there is enough space to fit the last item in the menu) the last menu item is shown in stead of the menu button?

*
*I made the following screenshots with my browser window at a 1125 pixels width, but the width can vary depending on the number of menu items and the length of the menu items.*

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:** in the JS code panel , right before `function updateNav() {`add this code to get the total width of all `li` elements in the horizontal menu dynamically:

```
 //calculate total width of the horizontal menu
 var hMenuTotalWidth = 0;
 $('.visible-links li').each(function(){
     hMenuTotalWidth += $(this).width();
 });

 //this line calls the function to fix the bug when the first loads for the first time
 updateNav();
```

Then on line 37, change this line:

```
if(availableSpace > breaks[breaks.length-1] ){
```

to

```
  if(availableSpace > breaks[breaks.length-1] || $(window).width() > hMenuTotalWidth){
```

**codepen:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyaZRJ**

*hopefully this will work now*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :)

It doesn't solve my problem though. I will use the menu on a multilingual website, where the number of menu items AND the length of the labels inside the menu items vary quite a bit, so I can't set a fixed number like `< 1125`. The solution should be flexible and scale with the content.

Comment: @Bueno, I've updated the code, check and I hope it will work now.

Comment: Thanks again, your help is much appreciated. I checked your codepen and unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I also tried it in my own code but to no avail. The button still replaces the last menu item when the page is loaded.

Comment: @Bueno, you mean other than when the page *first loads* it is working correctly and well as you re-size the window?

Comment: @Bueno, you are right, but it just needed a little fix, just add this `updateNav();` to do the job.. the above code is updated